# Losing focus/stealing focus in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

While running my application in debugging mood in visual studio 2013 it keeps loosing focus from my browser and the IDE. If i stop debugging then the problem doesn't occur.
I am using windows 8.1. 
This is being one heck of a problem and cant find a proper solution. Would be a great help anyone can give me solution for it.

Comment: Can you please explain what are your trying to archive? Why is losing the focus a problem and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. Because I have the same exact problem.

Comment: I also have the same problem I think.  When I run my web app from Visual Studio to debug it, the chrome or IE will constants get and lose focus.  Even if I am in a different application, such as Outlook or Word, chrome or IE will continue to randomly steal focus.  Did you figure out what was going on????

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running windows 8.1 on a Lenovo w540. To solve this I used the code from this [post](http://adrianswall.com/?p=193). It turned out to be wermgr.exe trying to report an error in xrdd.exe which is the X-Rite Device Services Manager. This has never run correctly on my machine. I still get warnings about my monitors needing to be re-profiled for colour calibration.

Anyway I'm not sure if the problem lies with windows reporting the error or xrdd.exe itself but I have uninstalled X-Rite Device Services Manager and this has solved the problem for me.